# error mapbox emberjs module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, import

I there is a problem in Emberjs with 'mapbox', this error: `Could not find module mapbox imported from grao-online-front/instance-initializers/mapbox`

```
import ENV from '../config/environment';
import L from 'mapbox';

export function initialize() {
  L.mapbox.accessToken = ENV.mapbox.accessToken;
}

export default {
  name: 'mapbox',
  initialize
};
```

Comment: well, what is `mapbox`, how have you installed it?

Comment: If you use mapbox out of the box then you should use it as a shin https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#standard-non-amd-asset or try https://github.com/binhums/ember-cli-mapbox

Comment: an alternative is to use https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify, which will let you import from node_modules without shimming.